# How to get a percentage change from previous values?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

The SQLite database is [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

How much revenue is generated each year on the invoices table, and what is its percent change from the previous year?

I have figured out the total revenue of each year, but I'm not sure how to get the percentage change of revenue from the previous year.

Here's my code so far,

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT) 'Year', SUM(invoices.Total) 'Total Revenue'
FROM invoices
GROUP BY CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT);
```

How do I get the percentage change value from the previous year?

Comment: Your question should contain sample data and desired results, and not rely on off-site resources for information required for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(strftime('%Y', InvoiceDate) AS INT) Year, 
  SUM(Total) "Total Revenue",
  100.0 * ((1.0 * SUM(Total) / LAG(SUM(Total)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(strftime('%Y', InvoiceDate) AS INT))) - 1) percent_change
FROM invoices
GROUP BY Year;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61hZLw394UdCrPivBpqEZu/0).

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to myself so posting here too,

```
WITH prevYear AS (SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT) 'PreviousYear', SUM(invoices.Total) 'PrevYearRevenue'
FROM invoices
GROUP BY CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT)),
currentYear AS (SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT) 'CurrentYear', SUM(invoices.Total) 'CurrentYearRevenue'
FROM invoices
GROUP BY CAST(strftime('%Y', invoices.InvoiceDate) AS INT))

SELECT currentYear.CurrentYear, currentYear.CurrentYearRevenue, ROUND((CurrentYearRevenue - PrevYearRevenue)/PrevYearRevenue * 100, 2) 'Percent Change'
FROM currentYear
JOIN prevYear ON currentYear.CurrentYear = prevYear.PreviousYear + 1;
```

Comment: You can tr your query here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61hZLw394UdCrPivBpqEZu/1 The results are wrong.

Comment: @forpas I'm getting the exact same result as your code with my code too.

Comment: Here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61hZLw394UdCrPivBpqEZu/2 you can see the results of both queries.